# Will rosin paper work well to protect my floor from spray paint if I slide it under the trim before I install the trim?

Tags: painting, trim, spraypainting, trim-carpentry

Looking to figure out the best way to keep paint off my floor when spray painting the trim.

My idea was to slide rosin paper under the trim before painting, and then remove it after the paint dries.  The rest of the floor would also be completely covered with the rosin paper.

What I don't know is:

- Will the paint stick to the paper and cause a problem when I am removing the paper afterward?
- Are there other problems with this idea that make it a bad idea?

Comment: Almost any solid surface should work if the floor is covered.  Spraying paint would not be my first choice for trim.  Any decent brush should be as fast for trim.  Walls, spraying might be faster.

Comment: Generally putting paper under the trim and spraying is a bad idea. The paint will dry on the paper and be miserable to remove.  Better to put down a strip of maybe 3 feet of paper. Paint with a brush and slide the paper down to paint another 3 feet of trim.  Then you are always moving the paper before the paint dries.  It just make no sense to spray trim.

Comment: @RMDman would it work to score it before removing? I read about that here: https://www.painttalk.com/threads/spraying-baseboards-with-floor-already-installed.24661/

Comment: @RMDman I paint, then remove the paper almost right away.  As long as the paint isn't glopped on, it's fine.  If the paint *is* glopped on, you can get drips onto the floor as it dries.

Comment: @Huesmann,  That's cool. I have done that as well, but the OP specifically planned on putting down paper and leaving it until the paint is dry.  We both know the likely results of that.  Op also asked if there were problems with his idea that make it bad...there is.

Comment: @RMDman oh for sure, you can't leave it til it's dry.  I mean, you can, but you risk part of the paper sticking to the bottom of the baseboard.